# Unbale to create a container in Cosmos DB Emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I am running `CosmosDB Emulator` and trying to add New Container from `Explorer` but after adding all details I am getting below error

```
Error while creating container loyalty-vd:
The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get
dbs
dbs/practice
tue, 23 feb 2021 18:39:51 gmt

'

ActivityId: 3505c9a5-a872-49e7-b30d-42ae48a3c21d, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0
```

Please see the below Image -

[image]

Can someone guide what I am  doing wrong here and how to create new container and database in Azure Cosmos DB Emulator

Comment: A screenshot would also help to see where this appears.

Comment: Updated a question with image

Comment: Thanks. That's unexpected, shouldn't need to worry about keys using the emulator's explorer. If you don't have any data yet, I'd try uninstalling and reinstalling clean. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-netstd21#uninstall

Comment: Also relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-local-emulator

Comment: I have uninstall and reinstall the emulator. Now I am able to add Container via Explorer. I am running Emulator on my VM (Guest) machine and I can access Explorer from my Host (MacOS) machine. I can see newly added container on Guest Machine Explorer but when I open same explorer on Host machine, I am not able to see newly added container.  Do I need to Import new .pfx file in my MacOS as new Emulator install

Comment: I haven't found any docs about import and export data between 2 emulators. So I think you may need to create new container and documents in it.

Comment: I am not importing or exporting data, I am getting this error at the time of creation container from explorer.

Comment: @ppb I saw you comment that you've reinstall the emulator and you could add Container in your VM, so the problem now is that you can't access your emulator(installed in vm) on your host machine. If so, what we need to focus on is network problem rather than emulator, isn't it?